# Retrieve files from firebase storage using only the name of file without an extension

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

i'm new to firebase and came across this situation where i had to retrieve the files using its name without any extensions like .jpg, .png, .mp3, .mp4 etc... The Actual problem is that I'm saving the files with specific names that i've already decided, but the extension is automatically added using some functions. So I know the names of the files (bee,car,bus,etc...) but not the actual name (bee.jpg, car.png, bus.gif, etc...) thus don't know what i'm supposed to do, to get the download url of the file using only the prefix names(bee,car,bus,etc...) . can somebody help me.....?

Answer (score 1):

The first approaches I can think of:

- Use the API to [list all files](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/list-files) and then find the ones whose base name matches what you're looking for
- Store the files with the base name (so remove the extension from the stored files), so that your lookup works.
- Store more information about each file in a database (such as Cloud Firestore, or Firebase Realtime Database) and perform the search on that.